# How do call a random .php file from another directory

Tags: php, html, random, directory, readfile

I am trying to call a random .php file from a specific folder in my directory.

If I place the files in the main folder (root directory), it works fine however, My webpage will have to go deeper at some point so if I am unable to call files from any point in the directory, this could get quite messy.

So this works perfectly for me by having the files in the same folder

```
<div class="col-sm-3">                       
    <?php readfile(rand(1,99).".php");?>
</div>
```

However, when I try to place the random files into a specific folder (in the root directory), It does not return the .php file. I have tried the following

```
1. <?php readfile("/Myfolder/".rand(1,99).".php");?>
2. <?php readfile("Myfolder".rand(1,99).".php");?>
3. <?php include("/Myfolder/.rand(1,99).".php");?>
```

And all sorts of other combinations of ../ , "/ , ../../ etc

I also need to be able to call files from any point in the directory ie "../../"

I am new to php and this at the moment is really stopping me from progressing so any help in is very much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Did you notice that point 3 is ```<?php include("/Myfolder/".rand(1,99).".php");?>```?

Comment: what error are you getting, and did you tried absolute path ?

Comment: You probably need a path using the web root, which might be something like `/var/www/html/MyFolder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided, it seems that you are not really annotating the absolute path where the file resides on your server.

As an example:

Root directory is: 
/var/www/hosts/site.com/test.site.com

You need to determine what the file structure on your server is and specify the full path where the files reside.

The web root path is stored in a variable:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

website for reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Where as an example the value equals:

```
/var/www/hosts/site.com/test.site.com
```

So in your specific case you can try the following:

```
<?php readfile($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Myfolder/".rand(1,99).".php");?>
```

Which should do the trick

Comment: Yes! This works! Thank you Rami. Just to clarify for anyone reading (because it took me a few goes to get it) this is what worked for me - <?php readfile($SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/home/mynameonserver/public_html/mywebsite.com/myfolder/".rand(1,2).".php");?> - my hosting is through godaddy so it is a linux server and the entire filepath must be entered for this to work. I also substituted readfile for include and both worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a pathname relative to the document root:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Myfolder/" . rand(1,99) . ".php"); ?>
```